# Google Sheets Financial Year Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, tax

Using the below formula to calculate the Financial Year from the Date (G) column:

```
=IF(MONTH(G2)>4,YEAR(G2)&"-"&YEAR(G2)+1,YEAR(G2)-1&"-"&YEAR(G2))
```

It works for that specific cell - G2 but I'm wanting to apply the same formula to the entire 'Tax Year' column.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJj8b.png)

Tried pulling the box down on right lower corner but this clears my formatting (colours of row etc) and means that the formula won't automatically be applied when I insert a new row.

Comment: Update: Did find this works for every cell if I paste into the cells individually but can't figure out how to just apply it to every column:

=IF(MONTH(G2:G)>4,YEAR(G2:G)&"-"&YEAR(G2:G)+1,YEAR(G2:G)-1&"-"&YEAR(G2:G))

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(G2:G),LAMBDA(z,IF(MONTH(G2:G)>4,z&"-"&z+1,z-1&"-"&z))(YEAR(G2:G)),))
```

Comment: Thank you - didn't work unfortunately - it was adamant that every date was 2022 - 2023 lol!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dsLpU48.png tested it prior to sharing.